# Find exact word match in C++ string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following strings:

```
std::string s1 = "IAmLookingForAwordU and I am the rest of the phrase";
std::string keyWord = "IAmLookingForAword";
```

I want to know if the keyWord as an exact match in `s1`

I used:

```
   if ( s1.find(keyWord) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::cout << "Found " << keyWord << std::endl;
    }
```

but the find function catches the `IAmLookingForAword` in `IAmLookingForAwordU` and the if statement is set to `true`. However, I would like to only catch the exact match of the keyWork I am looking for.

Any way to do this with C++ strings?

Comment: One possible solution is to use [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (regular expressions) but in my opinion, their use in C++ is a bit more complicated compared to other languages.

Comment: What is an "exact match"?

Comment: only the word `IAmLookingForAword` and not anything else, not `IAmLookingForAword123` for example

Comment: You have to add an additional check whether the match was at the begin of the string or is prefixed by a non-alpha character, and similar to the end. What an exact match is depends on what you consider as valid/invalid prefix and suffix characters. So, you have to provide the resp. checks as written code. For C++, these are all just numbers in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with `std::string::find` you can test if the characters before and after the word are beyond the bounds of the string, a punctuation character or a space:

```
bool find_word(const std::string& haystack,const std::string& needle){
    auto index = haystack.find(needle);
    if (index == std::string::npos) return false;

    auto not_part_of_word = [&](int index){ 
        if (index < 0 || index >= haystack.size()) return true;
        if (std::isspace(haystack[index]) || std::ispunct(haystack[index])) return true;
        return false;
    };
    return not_part_of_word(index-1) && not_part_of_word(index+needle.size());
}
 

int main()
{
    std::cout << find_word("test","test") << "\n";    // 1
    std::cout << find_word(" test ","test") << "\n";  // 1
    std::cout << find_word("AtestA","test") << "\n";  // 0
    std::cout << find_word("testA","test") << "\n";   // 0
    std::cout << find_word("Atest","test") << "\n";   // 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use regular expressions. Here's a quick example. The regular expression uses `\b` on both sides of the word "exact". In a regular expression, `\b` means that it should match only at a word boundary (e.g. a space or punctuation). This regular expression will only match the word "exact" and not the word "exactly". N.b. it's often easier to use raw-string literals with regular expressions because the backslash character has special meaning to both C++ strings and regular expressions.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::regex re(R"(\bexact\b)");
    std::smatch m;

    std::string string1 = "Does this match exactly?";
    std::string string2 = "Does this match with exact precision?";

    if (std::regex_search(string1, m, re))
    {
        // this shouldn't print
        std::cout << "It matches string1" << std::endl;
    }

    if (std::regex_search(string2, m, re))
    {
        // this should print
        std::cout << "It matches string2" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the word you are searching for is variable (i.e. the word you are looking for is different every time) then using regular expressions becomes a lot more complicated, as you have to ensure you properly validate input as well as properly escape characters with special meaning in regular expressions. Due to this, I would probably opt for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> The find function catches the `IAmLookingForAword` in `IAmLookingForAwordU` and the if statement is set to `true`. However, I would like to only catch the exact match of the keyWork I am looking for.
>
> Any way to do this with C++ strings?

You could define a helper function for this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
// ...

bool has_word(std::string const& s, std::string const& key_word) {
    auto const found_at = s.find(key_word);
    return found_at != std::string::npos
        && (!found_at || (found_at && !isalpha(s[found_at - 1])))
        && found_at <= s.size() - key_word.size() && !isalpha(s[found_at + key_word.size()]);
}
```

Then use it like so:

```cpp
if (has_word(s1, keyWord))
    std::cout << "Found " << keyWord << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize the input string, and then compare the tokens, eg:

```cpp
bool findKeyWord(const std::string &str, const std::string &keyWord)
{
    std::istringstring iss(str);
    std::string token;
    while (iss >> token)
    {
        if (token == keyWord)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::string s1 = "IAmLookingForAwordU and I am the rest of the phrase";
std::string keyWord = "IAmLookingForAword";

if (findKeyWord(s1, keyWord)) {
    // found...
}
else {
    // not found...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Tokenize the string, then compare each token size to the keyword size as you parse.

If find is true and the two sizes are equivalent you are good to go. Added benefit if the sizes don't match you have a else block for additional processing.